# Complete Cookie Consent: The popup cannot be closed

Tags: plugins, cookies

We have installed plugin Complete Cookie Consent on a bilingual craft site. Now we have the problem that in the frontend the cookie message can not be closed: You click on the close button, but the message pops up again and again.

What confuses us: In the local environment (localhost) everything works fine. However, as soon as we upload the project to the Cyon server, the problem appears. Both on the test link and on the live link. Both with HTTPS and HTTP.

We use the following versions:
Craft Solo 4.4.9
PHP Version: 8.1.17
Complete Cookie Consent: 1.1.1

Other Plugins:
Cookies: 4.0.0 (We have already disabled this plugin for testing - makes no difference)
DigitalOcean Spaces Filesystem: 2.0.0
Feed Me: 5.1.3.1
Freeform: 4.0.23
Redactor: 3.0.4
Sprig: 2.6.2
Super Table: 3.0.8.1
Typed link field: 2.1.5